# Excel - show different text when a value is cell is greater or equal to a given value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say cell `A1` contains a certain value and in cell `A2` there is a mean of some cells.

I want cell `B2` (in which the formula should exist) to show text "Err" when A2 - A1 >= 0.7 and otherwise "OK".

I tried the following without any luck:

```
=IF(A2-A1>=0.5, "ERR", "OK")
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer by *@mistersuraj* I created the following formula:

```
=IF(( (A2-A1)>=0,7 );"ERR";"OK")`
```

Excel won't show any error but it will always show `OK` even when it should be showing `ERR`.

Comment: What does your formula show ??

Comment: Excel displays an error saying that the formula is incorrect.

Comment: The only problem with your original formula is that you put in the wrong test value (0.5 instead of 0.7).  Using semicolon instead of comma is a locale-based difference.  You need to use the delimiter appropriate to your locale setting.  If you have corrupted data, that's a different issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It Seems you making mistake in condition part of the expression. It must be something like this:

> =IF(**( (A2-A1)>=0.5 )**,"ERR","OK")

This link can be helpful: [Use of IF statement in MS Excel](http://sooraj.xyz/ms-excel/using-if-in-ms-excel-to-display-conditional-value-text)

My Suggestion to add ( ) brackets was just to confirm order of precedence. So that expression in brackets would perform in chunks although it will work fine without brackets as well in case of simple expression.

**@teylyn: I think your expression is correct and giving right results. Your expression will return *ERR* when the condition is TRUE and *OK* when the condition is false**

So please think yourself:

1. **do you want to show ERR when your condition is TRUE**
2. **do you want to show OK when your condition is FALSE**

Moreover you can use, ROUNDUP((A2-A1),2) >=0.5 function within expression to auto format the expression result.

Reference Image:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel displays an error saying that the formula is incorrect and `0.5` is highlighted (I don't even if it matters).

Comment: In my Excel (2016) even the example from your link doesn't work and Excel shows an error..

Comment: It sounds like there might be an issue with the formatting or values in cells A1 and A2. Do you receive the same errors if you type the values and formula into a brand new workbook?

Comment: @PFitz You are right. I pasted all the cells as values (in my original workbook some of them were simple functions as `SUM` etc.) and it worked. I also had to change `0.5` to `0,5` (notice a comma instead of a full stop). How do I change my initial workbook so that in works as an empty one?

Comment: Does changing the commas to periods correct the issue in the original? If so, go into Options -> Advanced tab. Unckeck the box labeled "Use system separators" and enter the decimal and system separators that are consistent with your data.

Comment: I need to change in the original all the `.` to `,` and also `,` to `;`. Nevertheless, I always get "OK", even if I shouldn't.

Comment: @teylen, you must not change expression in question, if you want to add new expression, you should append it in question instead.
I remember it was:

=IF(A2-A1>=0.5,"ERR","OK")

before.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was that my Excel is not English.

Comment: How is that the answer? It does not solve your problem at all. See my answer below for the real issue your formula has.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your values is a number stored as text, so the subtraction does not work. You could try to convert each value to a number before subtracting, like this:

=IF((A2+0)-(A1+0)>=0.5, "ERR", "OK")

Adding a 0 to a number stored as text will convert it to a number and the addition and subtraction operations will not return an error.

Edit.

Your spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

The formula in cell I3 calculates the average of cells A3 to G25, which by the way, you could do a lot more efficient with `=AVERAGE(A4:G4)`, rather than referencing each row as you do (`=AVERAGE(A3:G3,A4:G4,A5:G5,A6:G6,A7:G7,....)`)

It looks like in column J you want to compare the value of column H in each row with the average, which is in J3. You start with the formula in J3

```
=IF(( (I3-H3)>=0.7 ),"ERR","OK")
```

When you copy that down, the references will adjust to the current row, so in row 4 the formula reads

```
=IF(( (I4-H4)>=0.7 ),"ERR","OK")
```

Now, H4 has a value, but I4 is empty. This will make the subtraction of I4-H4 a negative number, so the IF statement returns the False part, which is the text "OK". I asked you in a comment what the result of the subtraction was. That is an important part in the troubleshooting. You should check your values when you get unexpected results.

If you want to keep using your current formula, you will need to copy the average formula down, so it is in every row. Be aware that you will need to change the references in the Average function to absolute references, so row numbers stay the same when the formula is copied down.

Or you could change your formula so it always refers to I3, even when it is copied down.

That can be achieved by changing I3 from a relative to an absolute reference with

```
=IF(( ($I$3-H3)>=0.7 ),"ERR","OK")
```

Then copy down. The result is in the screenshot. In row 4 the formula will read

```
=IF(( ($I$3-H4)>=0.7 ),"ERR","OK")
```

so, it references H4 and still I3.

You need to learn what the $ sign does in a formula, and understand the difference between absolute and relative references and why that is important when you copy formulas.

Comment: It works fine (Excel shows no errors), but I always get "OK" even in cases when "ERR" should be used. It is something about my worksheet. Could you see my comments in the other answer, please?

Comment: What is the result when you put this formula into another cell: `=(A2+0)-(A1+0)`

Comment: The result if fine (A2=4, A1=4, the result is 0). I'm almost positive that your formula is 100% fine but something is wrong with my worksheet. I uploaded it at: http://www25.zippyshare.com/v/oShWUvzG/file.html